# Hard Scraping API

Tags: javascript, python, api, beautifulsoup, python-requests

If you navigate to the following [url](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/) and select `Search By` `Country`.

Then insert `AE` for `Holder Country`.

As the following:

[image]

After you press `search`. then you will notice an `XHR` call to the following [API](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/jsp/select.jsp) which is a `POST` request.

Here's it:

[image]

as you can see there's *value* for `qz` which i can't get how it's implemented in order to call the `API` and do pagination too.

May someone has a clue on how to call that API and do the pagination ?

> The best which i reached is the JS functions location which handle the encoding of parameters [here](https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/scripts/branddb-required.11080.min.js)

I've already tried selenium with proxy rotation service but i got detected after retrieving some pages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `qz` value is *"encoded"* JSON using `LZString.compressToBase64`

[image: dev tools screenshot]

The `qi` value seems to be intially taken from `qk` in the source HTML with `0-` prepended to it.

```
var qk = "ooooooooooooooooooo";

// if(!(w == 790 && (h == 600 || h == 590))) 

qk = "yj0IAlhpQGl9BLWmmmJ2WMuzofkYFis64bmU5/6mE8w=";
```

Certain requests require the number to be incremented after you make them.

You also need the cookie given in the other answer.

Comment: you are a true legend, this answer deserve a trillion thank :) thanks, you learned me something excellent today.

Comment: How does qk go from `"ooooooooooooooooooo"` to `"yj0IAlhpQGl9BLWmmmJ2WMuzofkYFis64bmU5/6mE8w="` please? I think this is what ahmed is also asking?

Comment: @QHarr It's in source of https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/ - not sure why they initialize it with a dummy value - but the "real" value is then set 2 lines later.

Comment: The `Referrer` header is wrong and `Accept` header is missing. This is not a "public API" though - they explicitly state web scraping is not allowed https://www.wipo.int/reference/en/branddb/terms_and_conditions.html - so what you're attempting is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

You need to generate a `wipo-visitor-uunid` as pass it to the `POST` request as a cookie along with a bunch of other stuff.

The code that generates the `wipo-visitor-uunid` is this:

```js
(function (){
    //generate unique visitor id cookie
    if (!Math.imul) Math.imul = function(opA, opB) {
        opB |= 0; 
        var result = (opA & 0x003fffff) * opB;
        if (opA & 0xffc00000) result += (opA & 0xffc00000) * opB |0;
        return result |0;
      };
    
    var _cuunid = 'wipo-visitor-uunid=';
    uunid(0);

    function uunid(force){
        if (force || document.cookie.indexOf(_cuunid)===-1){
            var value = navigator.userAgent + Date.now() + Math.random().toString().substring(2,11);
            var cookie = _cuunid + cyrb53(value) + ';expires=Jan 2 2034 00:00:00; path=/; SameSite=Lax; domain=.wipo.int';
            document.cookie = cookie;    
        } 
    }
    function cyrb53(str, seed) {
        seed = seed || 0;
        let h1 = 0xdeadbeef ^ seed, h2 = 0x8badf00d ^ seed;
        for (let i = 0, ch; i < str.length; i++) {
            ch = str.charCodeAt(i);
            h1 = Math.imul(h1 ^ ch, 2654435761);
            h2 = Math.imul(h2 ^ ch, 1597334677);
        }
        h1 = Math.imul(h1 ^ h1>>>16, 2246822507) ^ Math.imul(h2 ^ h2>>>13, 3266489909);
        h2 = Math.imul(h2 ^ h2>>>16, 2246822507) ^ Math.imul(h1 ^ h1>>>13, 3266489909);
        // return 4294967296 * (2097151 & h2) + (h1>>>0);
        return (h2>>>0).toString(16)+(h1>>>0).toString(16);
    }
}());
```

The `wipo-visitor-uunid` is valid till `Jan 2 2034`, so once you have it, you should be fine.

Oh, and that string that you add to the `POST` seems to be query region result, but I'm not sure how it's generated. More on that in the other answers to this quesiton.

Here's the code, test it out on your end:

```py
import json

import requests

query_string = "qz=N4IgLgngDgpiBcIBGAnAhgOwCYgDQgBs0EQYM8QBHASxIAYBaGAOSwAUAO" \               "AMzAHY0AYgHcAWtQCuADQD2WNAQBeADyRIhCgIIBFLABlpANQIARAEIBNABIQ" \
               "AVlwCi0gKoBZALwVK4mN4QBGfAB9Ej8/Og46EABfIAAA="

with requests.Session() as s:
    the_cookies = s.get("https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/").cookies.get_dict()
    the_cookies["wipo-visitor-uunid"] = "994c22024f522fd"

    s.headers["user-agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"
    s.headers["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
    s.headers["Referer"] = "https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/"

    end_point = f"https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/jsp/select.jsp?{query_string}"
    your_precious_data = s.post(end_point, cookies=the_cookies).json()
    print(json.dumps(your_precious_data, indent=2))
```

This should return an output that looks like this:

```
{
  "lastUpdated": 1616081900884,
  "sv": "www3.wipo.int",
  "response": {
    "docs": [
      {
        "OO": "NZ",
        "score": 1,
        "STATUS": "PEND",
        "MTY": [
          "Word"
        ],
        "AD": "2021-03-17T23:59:59Z",
        "HOL": [
          "PONSONBY DOGS LIMITED"
        ],
        "NC": [
          43
        ],
        "SOURCE": "NZTM",
        "DOC": "36/03/1173603_20210317.1919.xml.gz",
        "ID": "NZTM.1173603",
        "BRAND": [
          "Good Dog"
        ],
        "HOLC": [
          "NZ"
        ]
      },
and much, much more data ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer provided. the `qz` value is actually a dynamic value which got changed during the pagination and even it's the one which should verify to the `API` the country which you are looking for it. by other sound. how can you paginate the API for `AE`?

Comment: Just for readers. this answer is just a global call to the API where there's no control on **filter** by country as described in the question or even addressing the **pagination** method.