# Unable to communicate with API

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the following [website](http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=27&tableName=TABLE27&title=%E8%BF%9B%E5%8F%A3%E5%8C%BB%E7%96%97%E5%99%A8%E6%A2%B0%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%EF%BC%88%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C&bcId=152904442584853439006654836900)

I noticed there's an XHR POST request done to the following [EndPoint](http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/search.jsp?6SQk6G2z=GBK-5XLAu7czOFdfjUuHTAYgKR0_eEMKGxjhPU1umL6fMvFNJD1RI_wcVzU4.0.1XJSzWVN5IObR3kJsb3BvlpeojXfPYjwpr2t8_lgbPpta0eTMZ3fAHh3XXd5m2GOsbyI41E69hqNESXCfM3A7MBMrALnH3axfCz4P6C36htAd6nnfl9erYQzFBNe8x.f7aczfQq3CdjxNJs1lZbqzqNEMrBKjmOGKlnibCMWrqK_vQhB2n9pkCi25iVcWeGUogxOkVs8beZd0g_JQFCoTyNYQ7LtyC_6CUrLxT4gKTukA109lSIX9crv57LjaJsLLCto3I.8mQ9aJ0ygcaP3Hq1upLGPGFlRpxd7a0UPKpnPaFXgL) during navigating between pages as you can see within the following print screen:

[image]

The thing which am stuck in within the POST request, i noticed there's a dynamic value came after `GBK-` but i don't understand from where it's generated or how to obtain it.

if you just keep navigate between pages, you will notice the value keep changes.

An update according to the below answer by `Life is complex`:

this is how to send a `POST` request to the API:

```
import requests

# we need the value!
url = "http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/search.jsp?6SQk6G2z=GBK-Value"

# here you can add headers as you need!
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Pragma": "no-cache"
}

data = {
    "tableId": "27",
    "State": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    "bcId": "152904442584853439006654836900",
    "tableName": "TABLE27",
    "viewtitleName": "COLUMN200",
    "viewsubTitleName": "COLUMN192,COLUMN199",
    "curstart": "2",  # here is the Page number
    "tableView": "进口医疗器械产品（注冿"
}

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: What appears to be missing is an explanation of how `TextDecoder("gbk").decode(value)` fits into this. What is `value`? Is there code we can run to reproduce this output? I'm guessing you are observing bytes within the actual request made or response given? Is it a POST body? A GET param? Is `GBK-AutoGeneratedValue` the bytes part you are trying to decode, which you later refer to as `value`?

Comment: @QHarr Thanks for the hint, I've just updated my question. let me know if there's something else i can do.

Comment: IMO there is now enough info to repro and understand what is required. I have voted to re-open. Were there any clues in the initiator script?

Comment: @QHarr Thank you. what do you mean by `initiator` script ?

Comment: In your screenshot you will see there is a js file listed as the initiator.

Comment: @QHarr got it. am not sure but i reviewed it multiple times and looks like it's all based on function getpage

Comment: Does the changing 'GBK-' value hinder you from scraping the website?   Can you provide any additional information on how you get this value, because I don't see it under network > headers?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex it's within the `url` itself!

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex navigate to page#2 for example and you will notice the value within url.

Comment: I navigated through 5 pages and the table info changed, but all the urls stayed the same.  The urls ended with this: bcId=152904442584853439006654836900&CbSlDlH0=qArEraqhca7hca7hc5dt3IMoacxeue5otUr_q9RwH79qqq7

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome 91.x in U.S. English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235224/discussion-between--c-and-life-is-complex).

Comment: I spent sometime this morning trying to scrape your target site with `selenium`.  In my testing `chromedriver` just won't load the page no matter my configuration tricks.  I was able to get the site to load consistently using `geckodriver`.   I did note that the load time between pages can vary greatly.

Comment: @QHarr based on my answer do you see a way to use Python Requests (GET/POST) to scrape this site?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Man, you are doing a great job and i really appreciate it. But I've been working on multiple cases such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66739184/7658985) . for such scenarios, we usually collect the required post data and then call the API, in the current case am trying to call the API which return an XML version of HTML where the data is always there without need of Rendering JS! (actually that API is the one which feed the HTML source via JS function)

Comment: The lag which you see between navigating the pages, that's because ANTI-BOT techniques, but once you able to call the API! then forget about lag anymore! similar to the previous case which i shared for you!

Comment: Yes, I know the lag is related to ANTI-BOT techniques.  So based on your past questions have you already solved your problem with the website in question?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Not yet, still working on a solution

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I still don't think that it is possible using Python `Requests`,  but I'm ok if you prove me wrong.

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex i too feeling it's hard to be, but there might be a road :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CONCLUSION - 07-25-2021

---

***After looking at this problem in more detail, I believe that it is NOT technically possible to use Python `Requests` to scrape the website and table in your question.***

***Which means that your question cannot be solved in the manner that you would prefer.***

---

**Why?**

The website employs anti-scraping mechanisms.

The `GBK` values are only one part of these mechanisms. The table that you're trying to scrape has 1504 pages.  A new unique `GBK` value is created each time you navigate from page 1 to the next page and so forth.  Thus there are 1503 unique `GBK` value.

The site also uses a unique session management cookie for each page.

```
# page 1 cookie
JSESSIONID=0AC56294FE6857A236F0E68A9106E1AE.7; neCYtZEjo8GmS=5El51n08q7nzOG_bzzqhGWyfW_Lx9tCv1uZA6QjBcUq0rH0d1XYIvTKzN3MfNn2cZasqfZoM8Yo5NTpuq9gM.IG; neCYtZEjo8GmT=53HTPEbke3aQqqqm_6QLwIaUKu0tMygss.En464jhvNz1mMzbOatzmLLtv9x_xiCP6JaO_JzcbvHqtsnQYydBa6B_YjSg6sFm7cVBBOhB35_.TZuwDsbOnDinJkNwMs3AaMPtM83dP9YnogFKHpNJo5.RHMTKT6_XNPr0mxebR6stRrQ7LFfACcWqHHhbc.j6gZfZzxsgwnPE3RGP6aT9nYuMJbvK2EGrdAv0O12G03KTk_BMk.xLeEwrQq5VjyH1tB7t4wQ.jQ1geshvbDPCs8_VHCkd2.6uIag5Md.lngzeDshhSjMrmBjyy0HTqAXQ3; acw_tc=276aedd816272186939626726e424a5dd554d4b095225e2cac90fc6d2da583

# page 2 cookie
JSESSIONID=651AD12FD349FFB1842E08CA578EA37D.7; neCYtZEjo8GmS=5El51n08q7nzOG_bzzqhGWyfW_Lx9tCv1uZA6QjBcUq0rH0d1XYIvTKzN3MfNn2cZasqfZoM8Yo5NTpuq9gM.IG; neCYtZEjo8GmT=53HTPeKke3e7qqqm_6Q_YEqK9dBPNnJQF00YvHDMLHlJeb.4rrpTsgfwZxU0S5OXIAB2aduoOTmj7RuKIL.LUXRaRqfh5ZByuTFX3LxK1Ia3sr3V45c.PPx6Eas5EF5EkQztquzrX78QIbjrJUcQoKoOKcqgX5UuRIN0gCyGDyI6FFj.JbPhwYf65Hcx9BzDQnrlGAPHM3WGvmKf7OJnLY1SGIuxtdyVUE359Ll2lr0QJxUq1Dacqz_WsFa_ZantBbP7MklHX6J21wmDnyo6s4xCeeTYwsGq.kGUbE74Dx.QjQBCM_SiLKccTog8_EdBDg; acw_tc=276aedd816272186939626726e424a5dd554d4b095225e2cac90fc6d2da583

# page 3 cookie
JSESSIONID=2121D74E0EFCEC3BE104DAA2791481B6.7; neCYtZEjo8GmS=5El51n08q7nzOG_bzzqhGWyfW_Lx9tCv1uZA6QjBcUq0rH0d1XYIvTKzN3MfNn2cZasqfZoM8Yo5NTpuq9gM.IG; neCYtZEjo8GmT=53HTPeKke3e7qqqm_6wBfEGBZsTF9_uGtgepzPXNOzFh0RNtGcE1Cf4hEQNppVywcI5mk3SlLkzvNll6ovr4XmfL2Ujy3AFZR5leVY2H3_584At3GmIwmnsEjOx5v5e_lMon3AbX9t2W8UiLoK.9SBX0vgNRfkqdpyPjWKk3Zs8gQG0k3_6UwxGTvEwWkaWL8vquJgCGlvLEFTjNvd07eHiR482UfpLPFP6yAkx8Wi9pM79cL.26KE3U2L79hgBKLHyOdNyj3VKOkDsaXefNdPXd.YqT4kevShGxzMM2PuzqnuuQnW.GQ5mr9Rx8VxUjEa; acw_tc=276aedd816272186939626726e424a5dd554d4b095225e2cac90fc6d2da583
```

So you would need to acquire both the unique `GBK` value and the unique session management cookie for each page between 2 and 1504.

I also noted that site employs some type of latency.  The first page can take some time to fully load.  If you attempt to navigate to another page before this page load is complete you will get this message "请勿频繁操作!"

It's worth nothing that some pages took up to 2 minutes to load.  When they didn't load the message above was displayed.

***Like I previously mentioned you should consider scraping this site with `selenium,` which might work to bypass the anti-scraping mechanisms.***

### UPDATE POST (SELENIUM)- 07-27-2021

---

I have attempted to scrape your target website with `selenium`. The `chromedriver` continually fails to connect to the site. Even if these switches are used:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
```

I also tried using the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/), but that also failed to property connect.

Even when I set a high timeout period with either `driver.set_page_load_timeout()` or `driver.implicitly_wait()` the session still fails with `chromedriver`.

I was able to access the website when I used `selenium` with the `geckodriver.` There are still time out issues, but adding a `WebDriverWait` couple with an `expected_conditions` seems to overcome some of the timeout issues.

Scraping this website will be a long and arduous process, because of the anti-scraping mechanisms being used.

### ORIGINAL POST - 07-24-2021

---

*First let me say, that your question doesn't have enough details to make a solid recommendation for solving your issue.*

I looked into your problem.  I found that your target website uses some Javascript to dynamically create the `GBK` value that is used each post request.

```
6SQk6G2z:GBK-5lkb7acLMDDxywZsCHoJagJlT50f1gw4.jaVgaBpBcGZDs1T_pcR_OPFgvOm_6oM8PfyL3L6xDPxFqgIqgwbVAEw8y4jd0P5yTWo3dx1cNLnCOYTa4mVr7azAXa9YiDEhOz7M1Qsw6BJIOSq0QVp.Ng.NWri7ByAK6dwme99ZEOnjraxZex1xLVGakyVVCoOEhFGfphV8D1GDFKLt1dG.4_XuCPDIoLNGmy4Dzd92SxlNWCQ707A8tvqP7jQq2wyRBV0M3y0moSs8I03rIXeYNKE3AkMmI8Xp4M6GZd0seJqGvGrN7vA8lJbiBfmEgtcSvPZF0hrfkVRvQGq9uHRx9JOLtdkujsYHk6TW7rYBVsQ
```

[image]

This `GBK` value is used when navigating between the pages 1 through 1504.  I noted that the value changes for each page.

[image]

```
import difflib

# page 2
a = "6SQk6G2z:GBK-5lkb7acLMDDxywZsCHoJagJlT50f1gw4.jaVgaBpBcGZDs1T_pcR_OPFgvOm_6oM8PfyL3L6xDPxFqgIqgwbVAEw8y4jd0P5yTWo3dx1cNLnCOYTa4mVr7azAXa9YiDEhOz7M1Qsw6BJIOSq0QVp.Ng.NWri7ByAK6dwme99ZEOnjraxZex1xLVGakyVVCoOEhFGfphV8D1GDFKLt1dG.4_XuCPDIoLNGmy4Dzd92SxlNWCQ707A8tvqP7jQq2wyRBV0M3y0moSs8I03rIXeYNKE3AkMmI8Xp4M6GZd0seJqGvGrN7vA8lJbiBfmEgtcSvPZF0hrfkVRvQGq9uHRx9JOLtdkujsYHk6TW7rYBVsQ"

# page 1504
b = "6SQk6G2z:GBK-59tY9cXfYPiYfpgB1rj16jFZNwQuke.NUV5ZljqD6daOH4pxgaFcRE7bERjrvfoY4OTl5PAWUo70VNRIqnYOi_TQCSWzvrcCgfTtEFl_ZdMHRVLhosJLSFwHiPdVn4cXZ7VnF5xahstqJHD6EBfd71iZT8HQBmx1dssd7RWA2Gdv8lGhJbS0ZeaxIVkfK5qaO.lxHVvG_9cq4weBdHeUQlGlIWhxKFYePkTr9Jp0eN2yDTZljeX0XWWOxIjEkdj89FOqaNDB2slUE.54oC96baGe7lttoz_2AoTbjHSTjfDh.eSyT6vA6.5dP5X.4XsFVYSnYKIznIdkjTURmm3kjvGM_iQoYT3V5gAKs1c6r6cE"


s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b, autojunk=False)
for tag, i1, i2, j1, j2 in s.get_opcodes():
    if tag != 'equal':
        print('{:7}   a[{}:{}] --> b[{}:{}] {!r:>8} --> {!r}'.format(
            tag, i1, i2, j1, j2, a[i1:i2], b[j1:j2]))

        # output 
        insert    a[14:14] --> b[14:49]       '' --> '9tY9cXfYPiYfpgB1rj16jFZNwQuke.NUV5Z'
        replace   a[15:18] --> b[50:55]    'kb7' --> 'jqD6d'
        replace   a[19:24] --> b[56:60]  'cLMDD' --> 'OH4p'
        delete    a[25:49] --> b[61:61] 'ywZsCHoJagJlT50f1gw4.jaV' --> ''
        insert    a[51:51] --> b[63:158]       '' --> 'FcRE7bERjrvfoY4OTl5PAWUo70VNRIqnYOi_TQCSWzvrcCgfTtEFl_ZdMHRVLhosJLSFwHiPdVn4cXZ7VnF5xahstqJHD6E'
        insert    a[52:52] --> b[159:243]       '' --> 'fd71iZT8HQBmx1dssd7RWA2Gdv8lGhJbS0ZeaxIVkfK5qaO.lxHVvG_9cq4weBdHeUQlGlIWhxKFYePkTr9J'
        insert    a[53:53] --> b[244:276]       '' --> '0eN2yDTZljeX0XWWOxIjEkdj89FOqaND'
        replace   a[54:55] --> b[277:291]      'c' --> '2slUE.54oC96ba'
        replace   a[56:57] --> b[292:311]      'Z' --> 'e7lttoz_2AoTbjHSTjf'
        insert    a[58:58] --> b[312:369]       '' --> 'h.eSyT6vA6.5dP5X.4XsFVYSnYKIznIdkjTURmm3kjvGM_iQoYT3V5gAK'
        delete    a[60:63] --> b[371:371]    'T_p' --> ''
        delete    a[64:74] --> b[372:372] 'R_OPFgvOm_' --> ''
        replace   a[75:84] --> b[373:374] 'oM8PfyL3L' --> 'r'
        replace   a[85:99] --> b[375:376] 'xDPxFqgIqgwbVA' --> 'c'
        delete    a[100:377] --> b[377:377] 'w8y4jd0P5yTWo3dx1cNLnCOYTa4mVr7azAXa9YiDEhOz7M1Qsw6BJIOSq0QVp.Ng.NWri7ByAK6dwme99ZEOnjraxZex1xLVGakyVVCoOEhFGfphV8D1GDFKLt1dG.4_XuCPDIoLNGmy4Dzd92SxlNWCQ707A8tvqP7jQq2wyRBV0M3y0moSs8I03rIXeYNKE3AkMmI8Xp4M6GZd0seJqGvGrN7vA8lJbiBfmEgtcSvPZF0hrfkVRvQGq9uHRx9JOLtdkujsYHk6TW7rYBVsQ' --> ''
```

The `GBK` value is created with this call in the HTML of the page.

```
javascript:commitForECMA(callbackC,"content.jsp?tableId=27&tableName=TABLE27&tableView=杩涘彛鍖荤枟鍣ㄦ浜у搧锛堟敞鍐?&Id=60456",null)
```

This is the Javascript that is called.

```
function commitForECMA($_17, $_12, $_19) {
    request = createXMLHttp();
    request.onreadystatechange = $_17;
    if ($_19 == null) {
        _$b6(request, _$JI('ZM6r2MG'), _$JI("Op0YV"), $_12);
        request.setRequestHeader(_$JI("RACeXwDYXwcTV8Ur2"), _$JI("9wDYgwceLwDT7iCYX3Ce9FKyvHKwPFa"));
    } else {
        var $_16 = "";
        var $_11 = $_19.elements;
        var $_14 = $_11.length;
        for (var $_4 = 0; $_4 < $_14; $_4++) {
            var $_6 = _$kH($_11, $_4);
            if ($_6.type != _$JI("aQ6YPMK20") && _$kH($_6, _$JI('Cwbm7wKV')) != "") {
                if ($_16.length > 0) {
                    $_16 += "&" + $_6.name + "=" + _$kH($_6, _$JI('swbm7wKV'));
                } else {
                    $_16 += $_6.name + "=" + _$kH($_6, _$JI('8wbm7wKV'));
                }
                $_16 += _$JI("xx2J03Up2Hsl");
            }
        }
        _$b6(request, _$JI('iM6r2MG'), _$JI("IVlesYq"), $_12);
        $_16 = encodeURI($_16);
        $_16 = encodeURI($_16);
        request.setRequestHeader(_$JI("53CmOFDVz3CeXwoxBMq"), _$JI("wMbZz3CmOFDV"));
        request.setRequestHeader(_$JI("ZACeXwDYXwcTV8Ur2"), _$JI("F3UraMD2O3UpNMCgB8cT6w6QzRbenM1TTQbS2MbJBRDY9"));
    }
    request.send($_16);
    if ($_19 != null) {
        $_19.reset();
    }
}


truncated....


function createXMLHttp() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var $_17 = [_$JI("5sYJ3sVanh2fJslf0woqXJ1ga"), _$JI("osYJ3sVanh2fJslf0woqXJcga"), _$JI("ZsYJ3sVanh2fJslf0woqXWnga"), _$JI("fsYJ3sVanh2fJslf0woq"), _$JI("3sK2OQbeuMCR0h2fJslf0woq")];
        for (var $_16 = 0; $_16 < $_17.length; $_16++) {
            try {
                return new ActiveXObject(_$kH($_17, $_16));
            } catch ($_19) {}
        }
        throw new Error("您的浏览器不支持访问此网页");
    }
}


truncated....


function callback() {
    if (request.readyState == 1) {
        _$_J(document.getElementById(_$JI("x3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$JI('3FKyXRUxEYlTW'), _$JI("EHDxnHOaB3vE5HDxnHOSNMKQGQ6xOHK2z3Kw2Qne7MCm9FKyvhbwNROg"));
    }
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            oldContent.length = 0;
            oldContent[0] = request.responseText;
            _$_J(document.getElementById(_$JI("H3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$JI('OFKyXRUxEYlTW'), request.responseText);
            request = null;
        } else {
            _$_J(document.getElementById(_$JI("w3CeXwDYXwq")), '=', _$JI('eFKyXRUxEYlTW'), "<br><br><br><span style=font-size:x-large;color:#215add>请勿频繁操作！</span>");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking to see if it is possible to obtain the `GBK` value and pass it back via Python `Requests` in some way.

For instance this code gives me a Status code of 202.

```
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
           }

conn_timeout = 30
read_timeout = 60
timeouts = (conn_timeout, read_timeout)

url = 'http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/base.jsp?tableId=27&tableName=TABLE27&title=%E8%BF%9B%E5%8F%A3%E5%8C%BB%E7%96%97%E5%99%A8%E6%A2%B0%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%EF%BC%88%E6%B3%A8%E5%86%8C&bcId=152904442584853439006654836900'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeouts)
print(response.status_code)
# output
202

print(response.cookies)
# output
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie acw_tc=3ccdc15616274084596245338e08543386ba17e301ed12362cb2860b0af57f for app1.nmpa.gov.cn/>, <Cookie neCYtZEjo8GmS=5oWYI0i1mRB70b.XyuRJwTdiW_WgqfsIoOM8LNI8nfdTGyX4kfKTl0TDpV5HSMj2KIpgl8ircG4c9uAz_u50UkG for app1.nmpa.gov.cn/>]>


for key, value in response.headers.items():
    print(f'Key: {key} -- Value: {value}')
    # output
    Key: Date -- Value: Tue, 24 Jul 2021 17:54:19 GMT
    Key: Content-Type -- Value: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Key: Transfer-Encoding -- Value: chunked
    Key: Connection -- Value: keep-alive
    Key: Set-Cookie -- Value: acw_tc=3ccdc15616274084596245338e08543386ba17e301ed12362cb2860b0af57f;path=/;HttpOnly;Max-Age=1800, neCYtZEjo8GmS=5oWYI0i1mRB70b.XyuRJwTdiW_WgqfsIoOM8LNI8nfdTGyX4kfKTl0TDpV5HSMj2KIpgl8ircG4c9uAz_u50UkG; Path=/; expires=Fri, 25 Jul 2031 17:50:29 GMT; HttpOnly
    Key: Server -- Value: ******
    Key: Pragma -- Value: no-cache
    Key: Cache-Control -- Value: no-store
    Key: Expires -- Value: Tue, 24 Jul 2021 17:50:29 GMT
```

Receiving a status code of 202 is an issue when trying to access the website using Python `Requests`, because the request isn't being fully processed before the connection closes.

> 202 Accepted
>
> The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be  disallowed when processing actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until the process is completed. The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

I noted in the browser I get these items.

[image]

I'm still exploring how to pass these items in a Python `Requests` POST to get something useful back.

***I haven't looked at using `selenium,` but that Package seems to be the best option for extracting dynamically created content from this website in your question.***

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking time to review my question, but really i don't know what you need further to understand my issue?! also you mentioned that the value keep the same which is completely incorrect as in each navigate to a page, the value got changed [check-screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CQ7DcEO.png). also the second important point that the request done as `POST` request with `Form-Data` which hold the identifier for the page number [check](https://i.imgur.com/NMXNtMb.png) as you will find *curstart* key which hold the page#! So I know the required `POST DATA`

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect that the value does change during navigation between pages. The part of your question that is missing is how you tried to use 'POST request with Form-Data.' Currently, I'm battling getting block or my connection being delayed even in a browser. This is likely linked to me navigating the site too quickly or refreshing the page too many times.

Comment: i updated my answer to explain you how the post request can be made. but we still need the value first to make the call.

Comment: Thanks.  How do I get to table 27 from this page https://www.nmpa.gov.cn?

Comment: http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/dir.html?type=hzp which is `进口医疗器械产品（注册）(22553)`

Comment: are you around ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη  What's up?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus-

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated: this website employs a sophisticated bot protection. To crack this you will have to look into deobfuscating JavaScript to see how they're generating these `GBK` values.

Therefore, my answer will be a practical solution:

I'd highly advise using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), a JavaScript headless browser that uses the Chrome API. Now, this alone won't be able to bypass this bot protection, as a website this sophisticated is most likely using tools to catch automated browsers. HOWEVER, the reason I recommend puppeteer in the first place is that it has a wonderful extension called [puppeteer stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) which I have used successfully many times in the past. This extension allows you to nearly 1:1 emulate a real browser.

I truly think this solution is the most practical.